# Form validation issue using FosRestBundle on Symfony 3

Tags: php, symfony, fosrestbundle

I am working on a REST webservice (FOSRestBundle 2.0.0, Symfony 3.1.3) and testing the creation of entities. The creation itself works fine with a correct set of data but if I try to omit a required value the controller still says the form is valid.

The entity itself:

```
class Customer implements ExportableEntity
{
    use Traits\FilterableTrait;
    use Traits\UuidTrait;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     * @Serializer\Exclude()
     * @Serializer\ReadOnly()
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customer_index", type="integer", unique=true)
     */
     private $customerIndex;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="customerName", type="string", length=255)
     */
     private $customerName;
     // [... accessors ...]
```

The controller:

```
/**
 * @ApiDoc(
 *      resource=false,
 *      description="Create a new customer",
 *      section="Customers",
 *      statusCode={
 *          200="Action successful",
 *          403="Authorization required but incorrect / missing information or unsufficient rights",
 *          500="Returned if action failed for unknown reasons"
 *      }
 *  )
 *
 * @param Customer $customer
 * @return RestResponse
 */
public function postCustomerAction(Request $request) {
    $manager = $this->container->get('corebundle.managers.customer');
    // Internal usage only, no link with the WS issue
    $manager->setChecksEnabled(false);

    $customer = new Customer();
    $form = $this->get('form.factory')->createNamed(null, CustomerType::class, $customer, ['csrf_protection' => false]);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    //if ($form->isValid()) {
    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
        print('VALID');
        exit();
        $manager->create($customer);

        // Return 201 + Location
    }

    return \FOS\RestBundle\View\View::create($form, 400);
}
```

And the FormType:

```
class CustomerType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array                $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('customerName', Type\TextType::class, array('label' => 'Customer name'))
            ->add('customerIndex', Type\IntegerType::class, array('label' => 'Customer Index'))
            ->add('comment', Type\TextareaType::class, array('label' => 'Comments',
                                                             'required' => false, ))
            ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array('data_class' => 'NetDev\CoreBundle\Entity\Customer'));
    }

    /**
     * @return string
     */
    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'netdev_corebundle_customer';
    }
}
```

If I try to create a new Customer and omit the "customerIndex" field, I belieev that I should get an invalid form error but I ain't getting it.

I tried to change the "handleRequest" with

```
$form->submit([])
```

and

```
$form->submit($request->request->get($form->getName()))
```

to no avail. If I add a "NotBlank()" constraint to the entity itself it works but I am under the impression that this would be a workaround, not a fix. Did I miss something ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$form->isValid()
```

This line will verify that your submitted data respected all the constraints written in your entity files (with Assert annotation, for example  @Assert\NotBlank()).

So, you did not miss something.

Comment: Indeed as I said this particular way of dealing with constraints works, but how come using the form does not produce similar results ? Since the form "knows" which fields are required / integers / whatever, why won't the "isValid()" call use this ? By design, mistake on my side ?